# ConnectException during deploying application to Mule ESB

Tags: java, exception, mule

Could anybody explain the reasons of the next ConnectException during deploying application on Mule ESB?
What i am doing:
1. I am package application in my local Anypoint studio
2. Logging via RDP to Mule Server
3. Copy it into app folder after deleting the app anchor.
 After I restart server this exception does not repeat (during first deploy).
May be port is busy by another application, but nobody use the same port… 
So exception text:
Exception stack is:

> 1. Address already in use: JVM_Bind (java.net.BindException)   java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl:-2 (null)
> 2. Address already in use: JVM_Bind (java.net.BindException) (org.mule.transport.ConnectException)
>      org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnectionManager:73
>      (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/ConnectException.html)
>      -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.net.BindException: Address already in
>      use: JVM_Bind     at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native
>      Method)   at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown
>      Source)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
>
>    - 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>
>      ---
>
> 2015-06-23 11:57:56,426 [WrapperListener_start_runner] INFO 
>   org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy  - Exception caught
>   is a ConnectException, attempting to reconnect... 2015-06-23
>   11:57:56,426 [WrapperListener_start_runner] INFO 
>   org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager  - Stopping connector:
>   connector.http.mule.default 2015-06-23 11:57:56,426
>   [WrapperListener_start_runner] INFO 
>   org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager  - Stopping: 'null'.
>   Object is: HttpMessageReceiver 2015-06-23 11:57:56,426
>   [WrapperListener_start_runner] ERROR
>   org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector  - null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector.disconnect(HttpConnector.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver.doDisconnect(HttpMessageReceiver.java:52)
>     at
>   org.mule.transport.AbstractTransportMessageHandler.disconnect(AbstractTransportMessageHandler.java:251)
>     at
>   org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.disconnect(AbstractConnector.java:1656)
>     at
>   org.mule.exception.AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.handleReconnection(AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mule.exception.AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.handleException(AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.java:59)
>     at
>   org.mule.exception.AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.handleException(AbstractSystemExceptionStrategy.java:77)
>     at
>   org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:148)
>     at
>   org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireStartPhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:95)
>     at
>   org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.start(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:140)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225)
>     at
>   org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276)
>     at
>   org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155)
>     at
>   org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126)
>     at
>   org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80)
>     at
>   org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120)
>     at
>   org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94)
>     at
>   org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90)
>     at
>   org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72)
>     at
>   org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64)
>     at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:255)   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:147)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.start(ApplicationWrapper.java:107)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:48)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.guardedDeploy(MuleDeploymentService.java:420)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:186)
>     at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:160)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:56)
>     at
>   org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788)
>   2015-06-23 11:57:56,457 [WrapperListener_start_runner] INFO 
>   org.mule.transport.http.HttpConnector  - Disconnected: HttpConnector {

Comment: @Srinivasa R, thank you. *netstat -a -n -o | find "123"* where 123 - port num and then *taskkill /F /PID 3900* helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate the PID, where your port is running.

Issue a command to kill that process and release the port.